# Polymorphic schema validation in Clojure

Tags: clojure, schema

I want to use a schema to validate a request object. One of the values in the map determines which other fields are valid.

For example, these would all be valid:

```
{ :name "jane" :type :dog :barking true }
{ :name "alan" :type :bird :cheeping true }
{ :name "bert" :type :fish :swimming true }
```

Some fields are common. But others depend upon the value of `:type`.

For example, this would be invalid:

```
{ :name "phil" :type :bird :barking false }
```

How can such schema be expressed?

I'm happy to use either clj-schema or Prismatic schema.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use prismatic.schema's [`conditional`](https://github.com/Prismatic/schema/blob/master/test/cljx/schema/core_test.cljx#L265) to accomplish this:

```
(s/conditional #(= (:type %) :bird) {:type (s/eq :bird) :chirping s/Bool}
               #(= (:type %) :fish) {:type (s/eq :fish) :swimming s/Bool}
               ...
               :default  {:type (s/eq :animal) :existing s/Bool})
```

Comment: This looks great, thanks. Reading through the test code seems like a good idea as well. I have many fields that are common between types (i.e. like `:name` in my example) so would like to avoid repeating those in each cond branch.

Comment: I define a base type with the common fields, then `merge` it with the more specific type containing the specialized fields. prismatic schemas are just maps and you can manipulate them in all the normal ways.

Comment: Do you do the merge in each of the conditions, or can it be done at the top level?