# Validating multiple polymorphic values using Prismatic Schema

Tags: clojure, plumatic-schema

A little while ago I asked about [simple polymorphic schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23917495/24874), and the answer there worked well for a time.

Now the map I wish to validate has an additional value which is dependent upon another key's value.

A contrived example of the object:

```
{:type      :foo         {:type      :bert        {:type      :foo
 :foo-param :bar          :bert-size :medium       :foo-param :bar
 :method    :baz          :method    :baz          :method    :bang
 :baz-rate  :max}         :baz-rate  :max}         :bangness  :considerable}
```

The discriminators here are `:type` and `:method`, each of which has its own set of valid sibling keys and values.

Previously only `:type` existed, and the following worked:

```
(def ^:private test-base-schema {:type (s/enum :foo :abc :banana)})

(def test-schema
  (s/conditional #(= (:type %) :foo)
                 (merge test-base-schema {:foo-param s/Keyword})
                 ; other conditions here
                 ))
```

However now that there is more than one discriminator, the number of conditional branches would be combinatorial.

One option is to allow `{s/Any s/Any}` in the maps and using `s/both`, but I cannot allow the schemas to be 'loose', as unexpected key/values should be seen as invalid.

I also do not want to change the structure of the map being validated just to allow validation to work using this library.

Is there a sane way to achieve strict validation of maps that have multiple conditional sub-schemas?

Answer (score 6):

A snarky answer is that this may be a smell that your data model is less than ideal, and you should consider refactoring it to have nested structure like

```
{:type-info {:type :foo :foo-param :bar}
 :method-info {:method :baz :baz-rate :max}}
```

A (perhaps) more helpful answer is that I don't think this is easy with the out-of-the-box set of schemas, besides just writing a custom predicate for validation.

If this isn't desirable, I guess you need to introduce a new schema type.  Fortunately, this is easy to do in user code (or a third-party library).  Unfortunately, I don't see an easy way to represent these two concepts (strict union and conditional map structure) in a crisp and orthogonal way (without combining them into a single conditional-union schema, or having union be conditional-aware).  I believe there's a a way, but it's not obvious to me at first look.